# Mongodb aggregation taking average

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In MongoDb, I have a collection which has following data:

```js
[{
    _id: ObjectId('....'),
    data: [{
        type: 'internal',
        name: 'abc',
        value: 60
    }, {
        type: 'internal',
        name: 'def',
        value: 20
    }, {
        type: 'external',
        name: 'def',
        value: 20
    }]
}, {
    _id: ObjectId('....'),
    data: [{
        type: 'internal',
        name: 'abc',
        value: 30
    }, {
        type: 'internal',
        name: 'def',
        value: 40
    }, {
        type: 'external',
        name: 'def',
        value: 10
    }]
}]
```

Now If I want to group by **type** and take average of **value** field, I can do like

```js
db.testcollection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$data'}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$data.type', avg: {$avg: '$data.value'}}}
]);
```

But, If values of one document of same type has to be treated has one value(sum of both) and then average has to be calculated, what will be the query ?

In my example for type **internal** it should be:

```
((60+20)+(30+40))/2
```

rather than

```
(60+20+30+40)/4
```

Comment: @Anand Jayabalan SO adds the correct syntax highlighting if the post has the correct language tag. When editing, add the Javascript tag instead and the format will fix itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 $group phases.  The first one is used to compute the sum within a document and the second one is used to compute the average across documents.

```js
db.testcollection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$data"}, 
    {$group: {_id: {_id:"$_id", type:"$data.type"}, sum:{"$sum": "$data.value"}}}
    {$group:{_id:"$_id.type", avg:{"$avg":"$sum"}}}
]);
```